# Check whether child process terminated in C

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child, waitpid

`waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)` stops the calling process until one of its children changes status (so not necessarily terminated). I want to check after calling `waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)`, whether a specific child terminated, I'm doing this by using `waitpid(<child_pid>, NULL, WNOHANG)`, and afaik with `WNOHANG` as an option the execution of the process with `<child_pid>` won't be interrupted and it should return `0` if its active,
else the `<child_pid>` and `-1` if an error occurred.

But my program returns `-1`, instead of some value `>= 0` as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){ 
                pid_t child_pid = getpid();
                printf("Child %d starts\n", child_pid); 
                sleep(5);
                printf("Child %d exits\n", child_pid);
                return 0;
        }   
        // parent waits for child status change
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0); 
        printf("Parent waited\n");
        // parents checks status
        pid_t status = waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG);
        printf("%d status is %d\n", pid, status);

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Child 7823 starts
Child 7823 exits
Parent waited
7823 status is -1
```

Comment: You have two `waitpid` calls. The first one has already "reaped" the child process. `waitpid` will not work on the same pid again after that. Just use the result of the first `waitpid`. Not sure why you need to call it twice.

Comment: but how do I know if the process terminated then? it also could just change status, to make it more clear: assume I have multiple processes running performing different tasks, how do I know which of them just terminated?

Comment: What do you mean? The first `waitpid` will block until the child process changes status (usually due to termination). When that `waitpid` returns you can check the `status` value to determine what the state of the child is. Note, by `status` I mean the second parameter to the `waitpid` function. Pass in an `int *` instead of NULL for that param to get the status. The return value of `waitpid` gives the pid of the child that changed status. It's all in the [waitpid man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid). It even has an example code that is similar to your code but done in the right way.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it working now, I understand why you were confused by the two waitpid statements, with the 1st one I wanted to prevent a loop, thought this would not be good practice, but as it seems its how you do it. The "release the resources" part in the man page, is what you mean with "reaping" the process, right?

Comment: 'Release resources' and 'reaping the process' are essentially synonymous.  Note that you can often test whether a process still exists usefully by using `kill(pid, 0)` — send signal 0 to the PID.  If the result is 0 (success), the process still existed as a non-zombie process that you could signal.  Otherwise, it doesn't (it's a zombie; it has been reaped; it has changed ID by executing a setUID program, …).